# NInject and multi-threading issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, ninject

We are using Entity framework 4 for our web application and Ninject as our DI container. We have a log table to log everything that happens in our application and also we have backend WCF workflow service which again writes log into log table.

For all requests coming from the web we use

```
StandardScopeCallbacks.Request(ctx);
```

and for everything in the backend we use

```
StandardScopeCallbacks.ThreadScope(ctx);
```

our logging method is very simple

```
 public void Log(string message, LogLevel level)
        {
             var log = new ApplicationLog()
                    {
                        LogDate = DateTime.Now,
                        Message = message,
                        LogLevel = Enum.GetName(typeof(LogLevel), level)
                    };

                    db.ApplicationLog.Add(log);
                    db.SaveChanges();          
        }
```

Problem :
If we have more threads running then we get an exception

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed
>   because there are other threads running in the session.     at
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()     at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[]
>   buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName,
>   TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout,
>   SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj,
>   Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     at
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest
>   transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso,
>   SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean
>   isDelegateControlRequest)     at
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   iso, String transactionName)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   iso)     at 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel)     at 
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel
>   isolationLevel)

I know I can create new context using "using" statement and write ti Log table without any issue. But I don't want to do this as this will make everything slower then creating Context in threadscope.

What is the best way to handle such a scenario? I need the implementation that will have least execution time.

Please leave a comment if you need more information. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where does the variable db come from? Is it injected in the constructor of whatever class your Log method is residing in? And db is your EF context?

Comment: I hope you are well aware that EVERY major logging framework has appenders which write directly into a databse of your choice. Why do you reinvent the wheel? And also please provide more context so that we can help you

Comment: have you every tried `lock(db)`{ ... } inside your `Log` method?

Comment: thank you all for your comments. I know we can use logging framework and get rid of all the problems. But we need this for intermediate fix. yes db is EF context and injected from jInject.

Comment: I can you lock(db){..} and also using(var db = new DBContext()) {...}.. but i still want to use the same context created for my thread using Ninject.

Comment: We are letting Ninject create new context per thread for us. And this example might not be just logging. It might be updating status table or something else. For example IIS spawns 16 threads to load same windows workflows 16 times..and one of the activity is to update status table ... then I have this exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

Answer (score 1):

You should listen to Daniel's comment. NLog and Log4Net are better options.

I would not recommend locking on db as Jalalx mentioned, because it could end up slowing execution around the locks if you have a lot of logs. If you don't have a ton writing to logs, then sure give it a try.

Two options--

1. Register your db connection/context as per thread -- then you don't have to worry about cross- thread sharing, it won't happen.
2. Create a "DbConnectionFactory" that creates db connections/contexts that you can call within the context of each thread/execution.

So basically its either let Ninject manage it, or create an abstraction so that you can manage it yourself.

Btw, isn't ninject the slowest DI framework out there for .NET?

Comment: I don't see why ninjects speed is a concern here. If someone is using an ORM to write logs into a database I wouldn't worry about the DI container ;)

Comment: @DanielMarbach Yeah its completely not a concern. I only bring it up because i find that people for the most part are unaware, especially since its used in a variety of microsoft books

Comment: i agree with @Micah and DanielMarbach. We are letting Ninject create new context per thread for us. And this example might not be just logging. It might be updating status table or something else. For example IIS spawns 16 threads to load same windows workflows 16 times..and one of the activity is to update status table ... then I have this exception System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

Comment: that sounds like you're not really keeping the db connection per-thread. I would advise that you do add NLog or log4net to your project, not to instantly redo your logging, but so that you can add in logging statements around your db code/calls to monitor what thread things are actually happening on. (They both show the thread id in the output). That will help you diagnose.